# Highlight text as typed that matches array from recordset. Create qTip when hovering over highlighted text

Tags: jquery, json, textarea, highlight, qtip2

I know generally how to approach this, but my jQuery skills aren't quite up to par. Any help would be much appreciated! Here's what I'm trying to do:

1) I have an existing textarea where user can enter text

2) I have an existing database table with string pairs (string1, string2)

3) I'd like to be able to highlight all strings (maybe applying a `<span class="highlight"></span>` with background color or italics in my css) as the user types them into the textarea that match any of the string1 results from the database (the strings could be one word or multiple word phrases, but would not be portions of a word). When the user hovers over the highlighted strings, the corresponding string2 appears in a basic qTip2.

4) If the user changed the text, the highlighting and qTip would go away if it no longer matched one of the string1 rows.

5) I envision creating a json array using PHP json_encode from the mysql_fetch_assoc recordset each time the page is called that would contain the string1 and string2 data since the string1 and string2 data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of complexity in what you're asking, but as a starting point, you may want to look at Craig's Google translate demo on the qTip site that does a little bit of what you're asking.  When the user highlights a word, it does a Google translation on the selected item and displays the translation in a qTip:

http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#translate

Comment: Thanks for the response and the suggestion kiddailey. That demo is very helpful but I was having trouble with creating the array to highlight words in the textarea. Looking at some other SO posts it sounds like I need to use json_encode for the array and then create a div underneath the textarea for the highlighting and make the textarea transparent. I'll keep plugging away at it-- I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you use a hidden TEXTAREA to keep track of the edited text and display the highlighted content in a DIV, IFRAME, etc.?  Something along the lines of a javascript WYSIWYG editor such as TinyMCE:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

or CKEditor:

http://ckeditor.com/demo

That would give you the ability to highlight the text however you want without having to worry about wrapping/positioning matching up.